# Delphi - Tratamento de exceções em threads

Tags: delphi, exceção, thread

Escrevi uma thread em Delphi com tratamento de exceções, mas quando a exceção acontece a operação é abortada e não cai no bloco except. Existe algum tratamento especifico de exceções dentro de threads?

```
procedure TThreadEnvioJSONsWS.Execute;
var
  vErro: String;
begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);

    vSucesso := False;

    TSistema.retornaInstancia.adicionaMensagemLog('Iniciando a geração dos dados.', cOperacaoLog);

    if not(envioWSEmpresa(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    if not(envioWSAparelhos(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    if not(envioWSApontamentos(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    if not(envioWSOperadores(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    if not(envioWSRiguers(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    if not(envioWSAparelhosOrdens(vErro)) then
      raise Exception.Create(vErro);

    vSucesso := True;
  except
    on e:Exception do
    begin
      vMensagemErro := 'Falha no envio das informações.'+ sLineBreak+     e.message;
      TSistema.retornaInstancia.adicionaMensagemLog(vMensagemErro, cOperacaoLog);
    end;
  end;

  CoUninitialize;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema era causado pois o tipo de exceção não era on "Exception", portanto, não caia no bloco "on e:Exception do".

Answer (score 0):

Adicione seu código para ficar mais claro, mas é algo parecido com isso.

```
procedure TSuaThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    ......
  except
    ... seu tratamento da exceção ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: sim, eu faço dessa forma, mas quando explode a exceção a rotina é abortada e não cai no bloco except.